# ((DateTime)dtArrayToPickFromDB[0]).ToShortDateString()

Tags: c#

`((DateTime)dtArrayToPickFromDB[0]).ToShortDateString()`
how can i make it empty in immediate window of the Asp.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inspecting the return value from a method call (`ToShortDateString()`), so you cannot edit the value shown in the immediate window. This is only possible for fields and properties.